# Preventing Rails to load assets from inside a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, spree

I am using [solidus](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus) project.
For customizing the frontend,I need to remove some core javascript files,So I create a rails extension.
The only way I find to remove such files is to create an empty file with the same name and path inside my extension (overriding each with an empty file).
Is there any cleaner way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is simple:

So, i try to disable jquery.validate plugin, coming with solidus.

I write func and can see a error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined

which fired from jquery.validate.min.js

I can see header of this file:

    `/*!
    * jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1
    *
    * http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
    * http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation
    *
    * Copyright 2013 Jörn Zaefferer
    * Released under the MIT license:
    *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
    */`

i seek my gems directory:

`grep -r "jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1" .`

and see: it placed in:

`./solidus_frontend-1.2.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min.js: * jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1
    ./solidus_frontend-1.2.0/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.validate/additional-methods.min.js: * jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1`

but, if i simple remove it from gems folder - effect dissapeared, when i renew or update gem solidus.

for that, i make two files in app/assets/javascript/jquery.validate folder within content (stubs).

After that, i found called this jquery functions code and remove it too.

Comment: Thank You Sergeij, But solution is same as mine, I looking for a cleaner way.